# Conditionally add operations to pipeline in Combine (Swift)

Tags: swift, combine

Is there a way to conditionally execute the parts of the pipeline ? Say in the code below i would want a bool which determines whether the api call and the debounce are executed or not (if true execute the debounce and api call, if false erase without them) ?

```
    var flag: Bool // true: validate university via server, 
                   // false: only validate with operations before debounce and flat map

    init(flag: Bool) {
        self.flag = flag
        
        validate
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] value in
                self?.loading = false
                self?.validated = value
            }
            //.assign(to: \.validated, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private var validate: AnyPublisher<String?, Never> {
        $value
            .dropFirst()
            .removeDuplicates()
            .trim()
            .filter { value in
                value.contains("@") && value.contains(".")
            }
            .debounce(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main) // from here on conditionally
            .flatMap { value in
                return Future { promise in
                    self.loading = true
                    Task {
                        Firebase.validate(email: value) { error in
                            promise(.success(error != nil ? nil : value))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: [I wrote this operator for RxSwift](https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/2b624d7c925d8b7910ef2f1e5afe177b) but I'm not sure how to convert it. Maybe CombineExt has the extras you need to do the conversion.

Comment: use .scan() operator ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is simpler than what I thought you wanted... All you need is a simple filter:

```
let sink = source
    .combineLatest(boundary)
    .filter { $0.1 }
    .map { $0.0 }
```

In other words:

```
$value
    .dropFirst()
    .removeDuplicates()
    .trim()
    .filter { $0.contains("@") && $0.contains(".") }
    .combineLatest(boundary)
    .filter { $0.1 }
    .map { $0.0 }
    .debounce(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .flatMap { value in
        Future { [weak self] promise in
            self?.loading = true
            Task {
                Firebase.validate(email: value) { error in
                    self?.loading = false
                    promise(.success(error != nil ? nil : value))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think that you understood my question, how would this filter conditionally activate the `debounce` and the api call within the `flat map` operation. With this approach the filter would not return any values (even valid ones) if the condition in the `filter` was not met. Thus values, which should be returned are filtered out instead of the operations.
I have updated my question to avoid further misunderstandings, thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer. Everything that you want to have happen before the filter goes in place of `source`. Everything that should only happen if the filter is true goes after `map { $0.0 }`.

Comment: Like i said, this would filter out any values if the condition `boundary` (`flag` in my example) would be `false` and thus not erase them. The values should however be erased without the `debounce` and `flat map` operations if `boundary`, which by the way is not a `Publisher` but a simple `Bool`, was set to `false` and run through all the operations and then be erased, if set to `true`.

Comment: That's a different use-case. You need a different stream for that.

Answer (score 0):

To not overcomplicate things I'll show a bare minimum example of how I implemented a conditional debouncing.

### Update:

If you want a 100% reactive approach you can do something like this:

```
var subscription: AnyCancellable

subscription = $value
    .map { val in
        if <condition> {
            Just(val)
                .debounce(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            Just(val)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    .switchToLatest() // You might not need this but most probably you do
    .sink {
      // Do whatever you need
    }
```

Here, depending on the condition we convert one publisher into a different one. Then using `.switchToLatest()` we jump to the latest publisher, discarding the previous one.

### Original answer:

This way is not fully reactive (haven't used the `.debounce` method) but it gets the thing done:

```
var timer: Timer?
var subscription: AnyCancellable

subscription = $value
    .sink {
        // Invalidating timer before condition check to not let it
        // trigger the debounced function after the `value` has changed
        timer?.invalidate()

        if <condition> {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                 withTimeInterval: 0.5,
                 repeats: false
            ) { _ in
                // Do the stuff you need with debounce
            }
        } else {
            // Do the stuff you need without debounce
        }
    }
```